# Need help in angular with json to save in directory

Tags: json, angular, web, client

I need a way to read a json file via angular, edit it and then save it so that the json ends up back in the directory.

Loading and editing works fine so far,
However, I'm looking for a way to put the json back into the directory.

So far I have only found out that it is not possible to change a file from within angular without involving the backend.

Comment: Angular runs on client browser, therefore it cannot just modify files in directories. You need a backend running on server in order to do that.

Comment: If you mean to upload a file, edit it, and then download the file that is possible.  If you want to read a file off of your host/server, you will need some code on that server to be able to read/write files there.